# Is static function a right coding practice in this case, performance-wise and resource usage-wise?

Tags: c#, memory-management, static-methods

There are many many similar links in stackoverflow, all which seem to be addressing complex functions (so quite difficult for me to understand what i really should go for). But mine is simple. I just want to know if declaring a function as static right way to go, if i can manage the same functionality even with a nonstatic approach? Which approach utilizes more memory?

Here's a sample code I've to implement, which is just showing up forms:

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Now I've to show this `Form1` from many other forms in my program. So should it be better (right coding practice) to write the above piece of code where ever I want `Form1` to be displayed, or should it be better to define it once as a static method in a static class, like this:

```
public static class globalvars
{
    public static void Form1Show()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

}
```

And then:

```
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        globalvars.Form1Show();
    }
```

I think if object of form is instantiated under the event where we want the form to be displayed (first non static approach), then the memory allocated for that process in the stack is destroyed right after its execution; while in the second static approach, the memory allocated stands throughout the lifetime of the application, and hence non-static approach is better right?

I know both works, and doesn't make a big difference, but still, which is the right coding practice, memory usage wise?

Comment: Do you want _the same instance_ of the form/dialog to show up, or just a form/dialog that looks and behaves the same?

Comment: @Anders Fjeldstad, All those forms are simple forms like "help form", "about form", "contact form" which is always the same. So it doesnt matter which way I show up. I just want them to be shown up. So which practice is best as far as memory is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I lost something there, but I didn't see any difference between them. The `frm` is a local variable, not a [static field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks for that tip. Yes they look the same. So it shouldnt make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

From a pure coding perspective any solution that avoid duplicating code is good. In your case you might want to add a static method to your Form1:

```
public Form1 : Form
{
    public static void CreateNew()
    {
        using (var form = new Form1())
        {
            form.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

EDIT: From a memory point of view, the two samples you provided behave exactly the same. And modal dialogs should be disposed explicitly (with the using keyword for example).

Comment: @Johann Blais, thanks. But doesnt this mean that `CreateNew()` stays in the memory throughout the lifetime of the application once its instantiated?

Comment: No, it is only a method call, it has no memory of its own. Only the local variables will consume memory, but they will be destroyed after the function call finishes.

Comment: @Johann Blais, how is your method different from my static method? Both are same right?

Comment: Yes but please notice the using statement to properly cleanup unmanaged resources.

Comment: @Johann Blais, oh yes got it.

Answer (score 0):

From a memory management standpoint since you're showing the same form in multiple places the optimal approach would be to implement the singleton pattern to ensure only one instance is used

All - I know this isn't exactly relevant as the question has been answered, but in order to answer nawfal's question regarding the singleton pattern I'm going to post a brief description and some code here.

@Nawfal - the singleton pattern is used to ensure that only a single instance of an object is ever used in an application. There are a huge number of different ways to achieve this, check out [MSDN singleton pattern introduction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for a basic introduction.

For non-trivial objects, e.g. classes this is the code I like to use:

1: Create a base Singleton class

```
public abstract class SingletonBase<T> where T : class
{

    protected SingletonBase() { }
    public static T Instance
    {
        get { return SingletonFactory.Instance; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The singleton class factory to create the singleton instance.
    /// </summary>
    class SingletonFactory
    {
        static SingletonFactory() { }
        SingletonFactory() { }
        internal static readonly T Instance = GetInstance();
        static T GetInstance()
        {
            var theType = typeof(T);
            T inst;
            try
            {
                inst = (T)theType
                  .InvokeMember(theType.Name,
                    BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance
                    | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, null, null,
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (MissingMethodException ex)
            {
                throw new TypeLoadException(string.Format(
                  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                  "The type '{0}' must have a private constructor to " +
                  "be used in the Singleton pattern.", theType.FullName)
                  , ex);
            }

            return inst;
        }
    }
```

2: Now inherit from your base class

```
public class myClass : SingletonBase<myClass>
{
    // this is a private constructor
   myClass() { }

   private void somemethod()
   {
   }

   public void SomeOtherMethod()
   {
   }
}
```

3: Finally anywhere you need to use myClass you call its instance as shown below

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // here you call the single instance of myClass
        myClass myClassInstance = myClass.Instance;

        // run the public someothermethod of myClass
        myClassInstance.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
```

Comment: @Johnv2020, I don't know what singleton practice is. Can u give code sample? Else let me see to that. Thanks.

Comment: @Johnv2020 & @Johann Blais, I dunno who down voted!! May be because the answer doesnt answer exactly what I asked.

Comment: maybe a singleton here will actually use more memory, since its always allocated, but a transient window that is displayed for a short while then GC'd (nawfal sais its an about window, how long do you keep tha open) is more effectively using resources.

Comment: @Johnv2020, looks soooo complicated, still thanks. I have question, how what is the advantage of this approach memory usage wise? How is affecting performance?

Comment: @nawful, firstly its not very complicated. Just take the code above and apply it to a simple console app. You can reuse the base class over & over again in all sorts of different projects. Secondly in terms of memory performance etc. this pattern ensures that ther can only ever be ONE instance of an object in memory for the entire lifetime of an application running. So in your case the form would be created just once and held in memory, you would never need to recreate & dispose it again. It also means that on your form you can access variables which were previously changed without extra codin

Comment: @Johnv2020, see in this case it does mean that the object lies in the memory throughout the application's lifetime. For functions as simple as showing up forms, isn't it better to create a stack in memory for an object and destroy it right after use? `So in your case the form would be created just once and held in memory, you would never need to recreate & dispose it again` this is what you say.